# Java code for saving in Many-to-Many join table with extra columns JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have 2 tables Foo and Bar linked by join table FooBar. FooBar has some additional columns of its own. The foreign key from FooBar to Foo does not point to the primary key of Foo but to `foo_id` which has a uniqueness constraint.

```java
@Entity
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private UUID fooId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fooId", referencedColumnName = "fooId")
    private List<FooBar> foobars;
```

```java
@Entity
public class Bar {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private UUID barId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "barId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<FooBar> foobars;
```

```java
@Entity
public class FooBar {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long fooBarId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "fooId", referencedColumnName = "fooId",
                    insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Foo foo;

    @Column
    private String x;

    @Column
    private String y;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "barId", referencedColumnName = "id" ,insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Bar bar;
```

Usage: Foo table already has an entry for `foo_id`. I'm trying to save Bar and FooBar using the code below.

```java
void doStuff() {
  // Foo already exists
  List<FooBar> refs = new ArrayList<>();
  refs.add(FooBar.builder()
                     .x("x")
                     .y("y")
                     .foo(Foo.builder()
                               .fooId(the-foo-uuid)
                               .build())
                     .build());
  Bar bar = new Bar();
  bar.setFoobars(refs);
  repo.saveAndFlush(bar);
}
```

On executing the java code to save Bar and FooBar entries, I see a SQL constraint violation exception complaining that `foo_id` is null.

Comment: I guess the `insertable = false` in your JoinColumn statements of `FooBar` prevent `fooId` and `barId` from being set in the insert query

Comment: That's added because I want the owning side to be the one side of the relationship, and not the many side. It tries to insert, that's when it complains that the `foo_id` is null.

Comment: have you check the insert quries ? and please set bar as well in refs as you added foo I think it's required because it's bidirectional relationship.